# SVG symbol not showing gradient

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, safari, gradient

How to probably display a linear gradient in HTML from a SVG `<symbol>`? I tried the following but somehow this only works in FireFox (version 63). In chrome and safari it didn't load the gradient. What am I doing wrong is this a bug or is there a "work around" for this?

W3 validation shows no errors for the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gradient Problem</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body style="margin:0;overflow:hidden">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0" style="display:block">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#AE1C28" />
        <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color:#AE1C28" />
        <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
        <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF" />
        <stop offset="70%" style="stop-color:#21468B" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#21468B" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <symbol id="logo" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>

  <svg style="width:100vw;height:100vh">
      <use xlink:href="#logo"></use>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Have a look at [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7jjxyy2vk) where I try to deal with all use cases of including a svg symbol via `<use>`.

---

**Update:**
Hmm weird seems like it works in chrome when the SVG is in the HTML. However when the file is in a external file (as shown in the codesandbox example) then the gradients won't show. I guess it is an issue with `<use>`?

Comment: Clearly a Chrome bug. See the [SVG 2 spec](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/struct.html#UseShadowTree): "If the referenced element is in an external file, then all URL references in attributes and style properties must be made absolute...before copying the value to the element instances."

Comment: I suspect this is a same-origin issue.  The HTML and the SVG are being served from different domains (`codesandbox.io` and `w7jjxyy2vk.codesandbox.io` respectively).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I just checked that myself, but the request to https://w7jjxyy2vk.codesandbox.io/vector.svg succeeds according to the network log.

Comment: @ccprog I've improved [my codesandbox example](https://w7jjxyy2vk.codesandbox.io/) it now also includes fallback svg's without gradients and I added a new page with an SVG what uses an absolute reference to the gradient. However an absolute reference doesn't seem to help anything. While doing this update I noticed that `<text>` element behaves differently when referencing to an inline svg.

Comment: The quote from the spec does not mean that you, as a developer, should provide absolote references, but that the renderer, while building the shadow DOM for the `<use>` content, must maintain a link that points to the original file. This was not meant as a solution to your problem, but as the reason why I think it's a bug.